# Confidence interval - No sample

Tags: statistics

"According to thorough measurements, the average waiting time at a restaurant is normally distributed with an average of $28$ minutes and a standard deviation of $5$ minutes.

Calculate a $95\%$ confidence interval for the waiting time."

So what I do first is that I calculate the z for the confidence interval $95\%$. Which is $z = 1.96$. And I'm aware of the following formula:

$$\bar{X} - z_{a/2}\cdot \left(\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right) < \mu < \bar{X} + z_{a/2}\cdot\left(\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

However, since I wasn't given a sample, I'm not sure how to compute $\sqrt{n}$, what would I do next?

Comment: You should not work with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ at here, instead just treat this as a random variable $X$ and use the Z-test for it. Don't worry too much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the waiting time $X$ at a restaurant is normally distributed with an average of $28$ minutes and a standard deviation of $5$ minutes, in symbols $$X \sim N(\mu=28,\sigma=5)$$ the $95\%$ confidence interval with the *least width* is given by $$P(x_{0.025}\le X\le x_{0.975})$$ But since generally $$x_p=μ+σ\cdot z_p$$ you can use the standard normal distribution table to conclude that $$x_{0.025}=28+5\cdot(-1.96)=18.2 \\ x_{0.975}=28+5\cdot (+1.96) = 37.8\phantom{}$$ Thus, the $95\%$ confidence interval for the waiting time is $$(l,u)=(18.2, 37.8)$$

---

Thorough examination means a very big sample (actually the whole population). That is why you do not have to consider any sample and you can take $X$ that refers directly to the population.